# Android Management API with service-account

Tags: service-accounts, android-management-api

I have tried **Android Management API - Quickstart** to explore device control facilities. If i want to use it in a server solution, what should be the service-account's role and permission so that I can access Android Management API with project's service account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Basic Roles for your solution. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic) to know more about GCP roles or you can read this [Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart#start_developing).

You can also check this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account#create_your_service_account) for your reference in creating your service account.